# Save large json array's to database.efficient way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to save a large collection of Json array which contains objects to mysql. I am using larval. and I created a model for object. so do I need to store it as a plain text or save to database using the model. which will be more efficient

Comment: can't you use jsonfields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Data in MySQL as JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json)

Comment: saving large json Arrays to database is similar to storing large String.you can use jsonfields. but considering performance you should parse objects and save them independently.