# How to query JSON array in MYSQL with AND

Tags: mysql, json

If i have json like the following in a column in a mysql database

```
[
 {
  "name": "John",
  "checked": true
 },
 {
  "name": "Lucy",
  "checked": false
 }
]
```

how can I select in mysql all rows where in the same object name = 'John' and checked = true.

The json objects may have more keys and keys may not be in a specific order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use JSON_CONTAINS:

```
SELECT * from `users`
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`data`, '{"name": "John","checked": true}');
```

Comment: Does that work if the json would be {"name": John, "male": true, "checked": true}?

Comment: Yes. Its not depend on another fields or fields order in json/request.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! First time someone ever took the time to answer one of my old questions so I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to match the string if the keys are always in the same order. Assuming your column is called `people`

```
   SELECT
   IF(people LIKE '%[
     {
      \"name\": \"John\",
      \"checked\": true%', TRUE, FALSE) AS 'john_checked'
   FROM table
   WHERE (people LIKE '%[
     {
      \"name\": \"John\",
      \"checked\": true%')
```

With the knowledge of this solution, you could create a shorter SQL such as the following. You may use this alone, or use it as a subquery within the where clause of a query that will return all the rows.

```
   SELECT
   IF(people LIKE '%\"checked\": true%', TRUE, FALSE) AS 'john_checked'
   FROM table
   WHERE (people LIKE '%\"name\": \"John\"%')
```

You can probably see in this that JSON is not ideal for storing in mySQL.

The better solution is to design your database as a relational one, i.e. have an additional table called `people` and a column(s) that link the data. Saying how to design this would require me to know much more about your data/subject, but you should learn about SQL "joins" and normalisation.

There are other questions that discuss JSON in mySQL, such as [Storing JSON in database vs. having a new column for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key) and [Storing Data in MySQL as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json)

As of mySQL 5.7 there are some json related functions. See [this wagon article](https://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/values-from-nested-json), and the [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: If you take a look at the question you'll see that I said the JSON object may have more keys and they may be in a different order.

Comment: So you did, hopefully my example of how you can match JSON using SQL illustrates the difficulty with it. I linked to two threads that have detail on the issues, they tend to advice using noSQL instead.

I'm less familiar with mySQL 5.7, but there is a link.

I didn't want your question to be left completely passed by.

Comment: Thanks, but I am wondering if there is a way to use mySQL functions for the select when any amount of keys can be in any order.

Comment: I've added a 2nd SQL snippet. Essentially you're better off: just getting the row if it contains `"name": "John"` then using code/script to decode the json; OR not storing json in mySQL and instead create a relational database with more tables (or using a noSQL solution). Only you know the solution you want to work on.

Comment: The problem with that snippet is that it will find rows where John is false but Lucy is true

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be done in postgresql:

```
create table users (data jsonb);'

insert into users values ('[{"name": "John", "checked": "true"}, {"name": "Lucy", "checked": "false"}]'),('[{"name": "John", "checked": "false"}, {"name": "Lucy", "checked": "false"}]'),('[{"name": "John", "checked": "false"}, {"name": "Lucy", "checked": "true"}]');

select * from users, jsonb_array_elements(users.data) obj
where obj->>'name' = 'John' and obj->>'checked' = 'true';


    data                                     |                value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------
 [{"name": "John", "checked": "true"}, {"name": "Lucy", "checked": "false"}] | {"name": "John", "checked": "true"}
(1 row)
```