# JSON dataType not support in MySQL

Tags: json, mariadb

I am trying to create a table `book` which `tags` column datatype is `json` But here is getting error message -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB' at line 4
```

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How to support `json` datatype in MySQL?

Comment: Why not `TEXT`?

Comment: JSON is a string, so varchar or text

Comment: @Mark I want to store all the information in json format. That in future It will make easy to fetch by using pre difined MySQL json query. See here to get existing keyword of mysql - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: So... why not native JSON database? Like CouchDB or MongoDB

Comment: @Chinmay235 have a look on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564060/4870935

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to at least MySQL 5.7.8. See [JSON datatype docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type defined by RFC 7159 that enables efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) documents.

Comment: So you have MariaDB 10.1 and you need 10.2 - https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102

Comment: @Mark Yes it is `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.28-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)` How to upgrade it?

Comment: @Chinmay235 You won't have it with "xampp" because even latest release has only MariaDB 10.1.21. [The blog post](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102) on MariaDB 10.2 says *...even though a JSON datatype isn't implemented yet*. Google how to install MySQL, it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: i prefer mongodb for json data, it saves your times, or you can use sequelize ORM for mysql(which helps you to avoid writing raw queries)