# import json data from an api to mysql database in python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I need to import JSON data from an API to MySQL database using python. I can get the json data in python script but no idea how to insert this data to a mysql database.

Comment: What have you tried? How do you want it saved?

Comment: after getting the api data through python, i need to insert this data into a mysql database. the api data contains long list of objects, lists. I converted JSON to python dictionary & then tried to access the key values using indexes which is working but how do i export dictionary data to appropriate table & columns.

Answer (score 0):

finally, did it. Saved the JSON file locally first, then parsed it using key values in a for loop & lastly ran a query to insert into MySQL table.

Answer (score -1):

Serializing JSON to string and insert string to DB, and make it Deserializing when you want to use it. I use this method but I don't know if it is optimum

[Working With JSON Data in Python](https://realpython.com/python-json/)

Comment: i saved the json file. Now i need to export that data to mysql in python. I already know how to run mysql in python but how do i create insert queries for json file.

Comment: Look at this: [Storing Data in MySQL as JSON
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json).