# Inserting json data into query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm looking for help for one of my previous coding challenge, so I have two table, the first one is Sales and the second one is Product. Which look something like this :

**Sales** table:

```
ord_id     item_id     cust_id     status     qty     total_price     order_date 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          A308        CS209       Sold       1       30000           10-10-21
2          A405        CS209       Cancel     4       44000           10-18-21
3          B476        CS890       Sold       8       6400            10-29-21
```

and **Product** table

```
item_id     item_category     item_price     item_name     date_created     date_updated      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A308        Electronic        30000          TV            08-10-21         10-10-21
A405        Furniture         11000          Chair         12-25-20         10-18-21
B476        Misc              800            Cutter        05-11-21         10-29-21
```

I was told to write a query to get a result set like this:

```
order_date     detail                                       total_customer     total_price   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-21       {"item_id":"A308","item_category":...}       1                  30000      
10-29-21       {"item_id":"B476","item_category":...}       1                  6400
```

The other parts are easy but I'm still confused on how to turn certain columns from the `Product` table into JSON and inserting that json into the `Detail` column as shown above.

I've done something like this to get the first part :

```
SELECT order_date, COUNT(cust_id) as total_customer, SUM(total_price) as total_price

FROM Sales

WHERE status = "sold"

GROUP BY order_date
```

Can anyone help me how to do this in a single query?

Comment: set its datatype to text.. and store json in it.

Comment: **What** concrete database system is this for? SQL is just the query language - not a database product - and JSON support is **highly** vendor-specific - so please update your tags with `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using

Comment: Create detail field as Json datatype in mysql . refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564024/storing-data-in-mysql-as-json