# Protocol buffer Database abstraction framework

Tags: nosql, protocol-buffers, database-abstraction

Has anyone heard of an enterprise grade database abstraction layer that builds on Google Protocol Buffers

I can foresee such a DB tool set would have great possibilities from mobile computing all the way through to enterprise system development.

Comment: I have found bufdb project on Google code but it appears to be dormant. From a high level inspection it seems like a thesis driven project.

Comment: [UPDATE] During a nice chat at BSDCan 2014 with some wise folks, I found out that Protocol Buffers are alive and well at Google.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon any key-value store (eg. Redis) will do? Maybe Riak would be a decent candidate as it provides a [protobuf API](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/protocol-buffers/).
Eventually all you need to do is handle serialization and deserialization but that should be a rather thin layer on top of a lightweight client which does not attempt to do any of that for you.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Interesting that you mention the Riak Object store, I have worked for many years in an environment that is known as a Business Object Server which acts as a n-tier abstraction layer that manages business objects (data / metadata only) above a relational database model which is hidden from the developer. This shares some similarities at a very high level to an object store although the system I use has many pre-defined configurable schema such as lifecycles, access policies, users, groups, roles, types, attributes etc... I love it but its not FOSS :(

Comment: "enterprise" and "foss" generally don't mix together very well.

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct. However, that does not have to be the case. We often make Enterprise more complex then it needs to be. I have seen some very scalable and effective solutions that depend heavily on Open Source. However, nothing at the N-tier services layer yet.